# Odd "notches" in Polygon when using OffsetPolygon from Angus Johnsons's Clipper lib

Tags: c++, polygon, offset, clipperlib

[image]

The eventual goal of this code is to make sure the customer is defining shapes that can actually be machined by our... uh, machines. To do this, we are offsetting the specified shape inward by the radius of the bit and then back outward that same amount, thus rounding out any parts that would be too skinny to actually fit the bit into. For the polygon offsetting, we are using Angus Johnson's [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) library, version 5.1.6 (c++).

But as can be seen in the picture this is resulting in some unexpected shapes. In the picture, I have offset the original shape(green, mostly covered by later drawing) by -radius using `ClipperLib::OffsetPolygon` to get the yellow shape,and then offsetting by radius to get the red shape.

In theory, this should result in the red shape matching the green shape completely for the case shown in the link.

What might be going wrong to make the above result happen?

Comment: Angus has indicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19797642/62576) that there are support forums for his Clipper library, and that he prefers to use them. (Links in that post.)

Comment: Mike, firstly I suggest you download the most recent version of Clipper (currently 6.0.0) and see if you're still getting 'notches'. Then, if you are, then post a small data sample that can be downloaded and tested. Thanks. (Also, the preferred support forum for Clipper is over at SourceForge where it's easier to upload binaries for debugging.)

Comment: Posted over there with a link to some code to repro it: https://sourceforge.net/p/polyclipping/discussion/1148419/thread/75d8b1cd/#4b59 Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had these artifacts also and in my case it was solved by CleanPolygons() before each and every offset operation. The problem was due to micro-self-intersections and/or duplicate points, which can be addressed using the mentioned cleaning function.